# compliation error while using Oledbconnection

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using `OleDbConnection` for connection string here but I am getting error at line

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
```

> Error as CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.ConnectionState' and 'ConnectionState'

here is my code

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel.Clear();
    string StrCount = String.Empty;
    string connString = "";
    HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string Filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
    path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Excels/" + "/" + Filename.ToString());

    File.SaveAs(path);
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    daExcel.Fill(dtExcel);
    conn.Close();}
```

I dont know why?

I tried the solutions from other link but it didn't helped

Comment: Have you defined the `ConnectionState.Closed` yourself?

Comment: @ChrisF: Nope, I didn't used it

Comment: What happens if you hit F12 on `ConnectionState`?

Comment: So you have a **local connection variable** and you have just called Close on it (needlessly), then you check if your connection is open or not. I think you could be a little bit less paranoid here

Comment: Like Steve said, this is totally not necessary. Just conn.Open() and in the end close it.

Comment: What is the value of `strFileType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me you have an ambiguous class or property name. `ConnectionState` appears to have two meanings.

Try to prefix `ConnectionState` as follows with its full namespace:

```
if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
```

Comment: I get error as `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.` at `conn.open()`

Comment: Okay, so the actual compilation error is solved! I don't think you should close it before opening, but that are just my two cents.

Comment: what actuallly i need to look at that link ? can u edit your answer a bit ?

Comment: Sorry, that was removed already. Don't close it before you open it.

Comment: The problem is that you are closing connection before it is even open. You should remove this 2 lines from your code:
  conn.Close();. 
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

Comment: @mybirthname: after removing that two line, I get error as `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`

Comment: @PatrickHofman: So what should I do now to work it perfectly ?

Comment: Oh, I see. You don't have an `else` branch, so `connString` can be unset if it doesn't meet all conditions. Try to change the `else if` to `else`.

Comment: when I remove `if` from `else if` I get error as ` CS1002: ; expected`

Comment: @coder that's not very difficult to solve. Don't you see that if you have an extension different from XLS or XLSX you don't initialize the variable carrying the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments on Patrick's answer, I see else is missing here

```
if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
```

May be `connString` is left blank as `strFileType` is not .xls.or .xlsx.